# How hard is it for for Russia to get New Zealand to extradite people wanted for crimes in Russia?

Tags: extradition

Does New Zealand have an extradition treaty with Russia? In any case, I heard recently that NZ is sometimes willing to extradite to countries that it doesn’t have treaties with. But how hard or easy is it in practice?..have many people been extradited from NZ to Russia, and many successfully fought a legal proceeding to make them sent there?

Comment: That will depend on what citizenships those people hold. Say someone who only has Russian citizenship will much more likely be extradited than someone who has both Russian and New Zealand citizenships. Which scenario are you asking about?

Comment: [There doesn't need to be a treaty for a country to request extradition from NZ](https://www.crownlaw.govt.nz/assistance-for-foreign-authorities/extradition/). How hard or easy is a matter of opinion, the procedure is outlined on the page linked.

Comment: Greendrake, I’m wondering about a person with U.S. citizenship residing in New Zealand.